# Assigning an address to an array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have been trying to figure out how to assign an address to an array of structures in C I have managed to have a limited amount of success. Here is my struct:

```
struct pdirectory {
   uint16_t  one;
   uint8_t   two;
   uint8_t   three;
   uint16_t  four;
};
```

Here is my first attempt at declaring my struct variable:

```
struct pdirectory *test = (struct pdirectory *)0x00001000;
```

Which worked fine and placed my struct at the memory location expected.
However I can't successfully assign an address to an array of structures.
I have tired the following code with limited success:

```
struct pdirectory (*test)[1] = (struct pdirectory *)0x00001000;
```

Which places my struct at the intended address and I can even access different arrays with the following test code:

```
void initialise_virtual_manager(){
test[0]->one  = 0x3333;
test[0]->four = 0x3333;
test[1]->one  = 0x3434;
test[1]->four = 0x3434;
test[2]->one  = 0x3535;
test[2]->four = 0x3535;
}
```

I know my code above is not right. I tired to change the array number in the struct deceleration which offsets the array entries in memory by the struct size (which is not what I am intending to do) I want to declare an array of 1024 strut's . Also with the above code I can access an unlimited amount of array's (which is not what I want, I want the array number to limit the amount of array's I can access). If someone can see what I am doing wrong or has any other suggestion to solve this problem I am having, that would be a big help.

Comment: With the first version you can use `test[0].one`, `test[1].one`, `test[2].one` etc.

Comment: None of your codes "place a struct at an address", instead you point to that address.  You say "declare a struct variable" when in fact you declare a variable that is a pointer to struct.

Comment: What about just doing `struct pdirectory array[1024];`? This defines (implying memory allocation)  `array` to be able to hold 1024 `struct pdirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, use the proper cast, since you seem to know how to point to an array:

```
struct pdirectory (*test)[N] = (struct pdirectory (*)[N])0x00001000;
```

Secondly, `test[i]` will performs pointer arithmetic in units of the **array** size. If the array is size `N`, then the array access will be equivalent to:

```
*(struct pdirectory(*)[N])((unsigned char*)test + i * sizeof(struct pdirectory) * N)
```

As you can see the above doesn't index the array that `test` points to, but treats `test` *as* an array.

Your array access should therefore be as follows:

```
(*test)[0].one  = 0x3333;
(*test)[0].four = 0x3333;
```

First `test` is dereferenced, and only then the array is indexed.